# Why do I get web exception when creating an XPathDocument?

Tags: exception, xpathdocument

Creating an XPathDocument with referenced DTD sometimes throws a web exception. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://todotnet.com/archive/2006/07/27/8248.aspx

> Because in the construction of
>   XPathDocument, there's an http GET
>   command to see if it can access the
>   DTD. It's not doing anything with the
>   DTD. It's for just in case. So while
>   XPathDocument is initially set up to
>   be a faster alternative to
>   XmlDocument, you'll have the
>   additional overhead of an http request
>   that needs to be resolved. Imagine
>   that server being on the other side of
>   the globe!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom XmlUrlResolver and then ignore the
remote DTD. Also, I believe you can set use XmlResolver = null on the XmlTextReader.

Comment: But the MSDN should clearly state this might happen. Looking at the XPathDocument you can't tell it will look for DTD on the web. Also why is the exception thrown? If DTD is not needed - works offline doesn't it? Thanks for the suggestions anyway - I'll try them next time!

Answer (score 1):

for those interested I've found a workaround to disable the dtd check

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
 settings.XmlResolver = null;
 settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

 var xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString),settings);
 XPathDocument xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlReader);
```