# .Net application asking for access to the internet

Tags: .net, firewall

I wrote a WPF application in Visual Studio that uses some .Net framework classes. It has absolutely no code in it for accessing any network resources and does not act as a server. I just received a pop up from ZoneAlarm saying this application is asking for access to the internet. I had written another application about a year ago, a simple text editor and after I left it running for an extended period of time it did the same thing.

Does anyone know why it would do that? Is there something built into the .Net framework that makes an application check for updates to the framework?

Comment: Are you using xml, might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239788/why-do-i-get-web-exception-when-creating-an-xpathdocument. Could you list the framework classes you are using?

Comment: I'd try creating the most basic application and see if that "calls home" too. If not add your code piece by piece until it does. Then you might have a better idea of what's making the call.

Comment: Is it deployed via ClickOnce?

Comment: Check if the destination site has "CRL" in its name.  The Certificate Revocation List.  Ask more questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: Goran got it, I was using XPathDocument in the application so it must be the get request for the DTD.